# Bootstrap 3. Is it possible to use media query to constrain the lower size bound?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, media-queries

I am using `container-fluid` for all my containers. This allows the layout to expand on a large display (good) but causes probs when a user shrinks the layout by grabbing the corner of the browser and dragging (bad).

Is it possible to constrain the ability to shrink the layout. Perhaps using media queries? Something else in the Bootstrap bag of tricks?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, hope it will resolve your issue.

```
@media(max-width:767px){
  .container-fluid{
    padding:0px 10px;
  }
}
```

Apply whicheven properties you want for screen size less that 767, you can change the screen size too.